# i have the following code, but it will not work. i am trying to create a script output:

Tags: javascript

i have the following code, but it will not work. i am trying to create a script output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var files = <?php echo json_encode($files); ?>;
    var len = files.length
    SLIDES = new slideshow("SLIDES");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        s = new slide();
            s.src =  "http://www.cashbackflorida.com/wpradmin/modules/wprrets/photos/<?php echo $result ->MLS; ?>/"+ files[i] +;
            s.width = "560";
            s.height = "420";
            s.alt = "";
            s.text = unescape("");
            s.link = "";
            s.target = "";
            s.attr = "";
            s.filter = "";
            SLIDES.add_slide(s);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: "will not work" does not describe your problem. *what* does not work? *what* do you expect to happen?

Comment: *but it will not work* So, when you have a problem like this, it is very important to explain exactly how it "will not work" - meaning, what behaviour are you observing (versus the desired behaviour), what errors you're encountering, etc.

Comment: Please tell us the used library, and describe what exactly is not working. What you expect your code to do, and what it does instead? What is `files` and what does it contain? have you looked at the console for errors?

Comment: There's a glaring syntax error on the `s.src = ` line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the JSON string to javasctipt object. You should do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xy = <?php echo json_encode($files); ?>;
    var files = JSON.parse(xy); /*<- this makes a JavaScript object from JSON string*/
    var len = files.length
    SLIDES = new slideshow("SLIDES");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        s = new slide();
            s.src =  "http://www.cashbackflorida.com/wpradmin/modules/wprrets/photos/<?php echo $result ->MLS; ?>/"+ files[i] +;
            s.width = "560";
            s.height = "420";
            s.alt = "";
            s.text = unescape("");
            s.link = "";
            s.target = "";
            s.attr = "";
            s.filter = "";
            SLIDES.add_slide(s);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i am still not getting the viable to populate: